# How to prompt the user for input once and for all before a while loop?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, append

I'm working on a Python script which takes specific data from a pandas DataFrame called "read_file" and writes it in a csv file. To do so, I'm looping through the rows of the DataFrame until a certain condition is met, and that is when I put the data in a dictionary which I use to update the csv file by using the "to_csv" function. There are surely less broken - and simpler - ways to perform the same thing but I'm leaving optimization for another day (although I'm open to suggestions).

I would like to know if there is a way to prompt the user for a decision regarding the way they want to write the data. Basically, I'm asking them whether they would like to:

1. Overwrite the file and then update it row by row (each time we go
   through the loop) via the append mode of the *to_csv* function
2. Not overwrite the file and just append data to it each time the script is run (this means it's getting bigger after a run).

So far my code looks like this:

```
i = 0
for index, row in read_file.iterrows():
case = row['Case']
first = case.split('-')[0]
second = case.split('-')[1]
third = case.split('-')[2]
fourth = case.split('-')[3]
fifth = case.split('-')[4]
if first == 'X01': # if1
    if second == '01': # if2
        if fourth == '04': # if3
            i += 1
            Ax = float(row['Ax'])
            Ay = float(row['Ay'])
            Az = float(row['Az'])
            ENT = float(row['ENT'])
            Ips = (Ax**2 + Ay**2 + Az**2)**(0.5)
            beta = float(row['beta'])
            date = row['Date'].replace("/", "-")
            totalP = float(row['Total.P'])

            data = pd.DataFrame({'Case': [str(case)],
                'ENT': [ENT],
                'total P': [totalP]},
                index = [i])

            filename = 'curve_{}-{}-{}-{}_I{}-B{}-D{}.csv'.format(first,second,third,fourth,round(Ips, 2),beta,date)
            if os.path.getsize(filename):
                print('Curve file not empty.')
                while True:
                    inp = input('Do you want to: A) Append the file. B) Overwrite the file. [A/B]? : ')
                    if inp in ['A', 'B']:
                        break
                if inp == 'A':
                    print('Appending... ')
                    data.to_csv(filename, mode='a')
                elif inp == 'B':
                    print('Overwriting... ')
                    data.to_csv(filename, mode='w')
```

However this prompt appears each time the *conditions if1, if2 & if3* are met, which is quite often. Is there a way to only specify the input once and for all?

Thanks

---

**EDIT:**

A sample file would be:

| Case | Date | ENT | beta | Ay | Ax | Az | Total.P |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| X01-01-ARK-03-001 | 09/04/21 | 0 | 0,193648827 | 0 | 15 | 10 | 3354 |
| X01-01-ARK-03-002 | 09/04/21 | 3 | 0,000183247 | 0 | 19 | 12 | 813 |
| X01-01-ARK-03-003 | 09/04/21 | 6 | 0,491674971 | 0 | 14 | 0 | 4111 |
| X01-01-ARK-03-004 | 09/04/21 | 9 | 0,757163602 | 0 | 1 | 5 | 2829 |
| X01-01-ARK-03-005 | 09/04/21 | 12 | 0,622608381 | 0 | 44 | 11 | 143 |
| X01-01-ARK-03-006 | 09/04/21 | 14 | 0,543299744 | 0 | 34 | 3 | 4732 |
| X01-01-ARK-03-007 | 09/04/21 | 15 | 0,624404717 | 0 | 16 | 9 | 3052 |
| X01-01-ARK-03-008 | 09/04/21 | 16 | 0,977021142 | 0 | 23 | 9 | 2178 |
| X01-01-ARK-03-009 | 09/04/21 | 17 | 0,97697958 | 0 | 3 | 12 | 191 |
| X01-01-ARK-04-001 | 09/04/21 | 0 | 0,440339098 | 0 | 33 | 9 | 1472 |
| X01-01-ARK-04-002 | 09/04/21 | 3 | 0,982879346 | 0 | 49 | 2 | 253 |
| X01-01-ARK-04-003 | 09/04/21 | 6 | 0,740821012 | 0 | 27 | 5 | 4100 |
| X01-01-ARK-04-004 | 09/04/21 | 9 | 0,48267087 | 0 | 38 | 0 | 3582 |
| X01-01-ARK-04-005 | 09/04/21 | 12 | 0,578068153 | 0 | 45 | 11 | 3320 |
| X01-01-ARK-04-006 | 09/04/21 | 14 | 0,541974323 | 0 | 41 | 0 | 2064 |
| X01-01-ARK-04-007 | 09/04/21 | 15 | 0,445777405 | 0 | 22 | 6 | 435 |
| X01-01-ARK-04-008 | 09/04/21 | 16 | 0,263795323 | 0 | 27 | 10 | 1251 |
| X01-01-ARK-04-009 | 09/04/21 | 17 | 0,708550336 | 0 | 44 | 12 | 60 |

and the expected output is:

| index | Case | ENT | Total.P |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | X01-01-ARK-04-001 | 0 | 1472 |
| 2 | X01-01-ARK-04-002 | 3 | 253 |
| 3 | X01-01-ARK-04-003 | 6 | 4100 |
| 4 | X01-01-ARK-04-004 | 9 | 3582 |
| 5 | X01-01-ARK-04-005 | 12 | 3320 |
| 6 | X01-01-ARK-04-006 | 14 | 2064 |
| 7 | X01-01-ARK-04-007 | 15 | 435 |
| 8 | X01-01-ARK-04-008 | 16 | 1251 |
| 9 | X01-01-ARK-04-009 | 17 | 60 |

Comment: Can you post a sample of `read_file` along with your expected output for `data`?

Comment: take the input outside `while`  and `if` before stating the `for loop`

Comment: Sure @not_speshal, I will edit my original post

Answer (score 1):

Ask the user the question before you iterate over the file, this way the question is only asked (and answered) once:

```
while True:
    inp = input('Do you want to: A) Append the file. B) Overwrite the file. [A/B]? : ')
    if inp in ['A', 'B']:
        break

i = 0
for index, row in read_file.iterrows():
case = row['Case']
first = case.split('-')[0]
second = case.split('-')[1]
third = case.split('-')[2]
fourth = case.split('-')[3]
fifth = case.split('-')[4]
if first == 'X01': # if1
    if second == '01': # if2
        if fourth == '04': # if3
            i += 1
            Ax = float(row['Ax'])
            Ay = float(row['Ay'])
            Az = float(row['Az'])
            ENT = float(row['ENT'])
            Ips = (Ax**2 + Ay**2 + Az**2)**(0.5)
            beta = float(row['beta'])
            date = row['Date'].replace("/", "-")
            totalP = float(row['Total.P'])

            data = pd.DataFrame({'Case': [str(case)],
                'ENT': [ENT],
                'total P': [totalP]},
                index = [i])

            filename = 'curve_{}-{}-{}-{}_I{}-B{}-D{}.csv'.format(first,second,third,fourth,round(Ips, 2),beta,date)
            if os.path.getsize(filename):
                print('Curve file not empty.')
                if inp == 'A':
                    print('Appending... ')
                    data.to_csv(filename, mode='a')
                elif inp == 'B':
                    print('Overwriting... ')
                    data.to_csv(filename, mode='w')
```